# R/googlesheets4 non-interactive session

Tags: r, api, google-sheets, token, googlesheets4

When I use googlesheets4 in R, I use sheets_auth() in the console and it works fine. But when I try to run it in R markdown, and when I try to knit, I cannot seem to get the credentials. Can someone walk me through the process? I've gone to the vignettes for googlesheets4 but cannot seem to understand it.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Well no I did not. I ended up just downloading it and using the sheet locally from Excel.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me

```
gs4_auth(path = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.json")
```

It doesn't return anything, but after that I'm able to write data in my sheet with `sheet_write()`

To get the credentials in a json file you have to follow these steps:

> - From the Developers Console, in the target GCP Project, go to IAM & Admin > Service accounts.
> - Give it a decent name and description.
> - For example, the service account used to create the googledrive docs has name “googledrive-docs” and description “Used when generating
>   googledrive documentation”.
> - Service account permissions. Whether you need to do anything here depends on the API(s) you are targetting. You can also modify roles
>   later and iteratively sort this out.
> - For example, the service account used to create the googledrive docs does not have any explicit roles.
> - The service account used to test bigrquery has roles BigQuery Admin and Storage Admin.
> - Grant users access to this service account? So far, I have not done this, so feel free to do nothing here. Or if you know this is useful
>   to you, then by all means do so.
> - Do Create key and download as JSON. This file is what we mean when we talk about a “service account token” in the documentation of gargle
>   and packages that use gargle. gargle::credentials_service_account()
>   expects the path to this file.
> - Appreciate that this JSON file holds sensitive information. Treat it like a username & password combo! This file holds credentials that
>   potentially have a lot of power and that don’t expire.
> - Consider storing this file in such a way that it will be automatically discovered by the Application Default Credentials search
>   strategy. See credentials_app_default() for details.
> - You will notice the downloaded JSON file has an awful name, so sometimes I create a symlink that uses the service account’s name, to
>   make it easier to tell what this file is.
> - Remember to grant this service account the necessary permissions on any resources you plan to access, e.g., read or write permission on a
>   specific Google Sheet. The service account has no formal relationship
>   to you as a Google user and won’t automatically inherit permissions.

(copied from here https://gargle.r-lib.org/articles/get-api-credentials.html#service-account-token)